# How to recount the count column in wp_term_taxonomy?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I noticed when I was importing the WordPress XML file to another blog the `wp_term_taxonomy` table counted wrong and didn't display some categories as a result of that.

Is there a way for me to *recount* the **count** column in `wp_term_taxonomy`.

Comment: I'm pursuing this answer this morning.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by calling `wp_update_term_count_now()` each time the importer adds or updates terms in `process_posts()`.